# Move/Carry non root GameObject to another Scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I'm having trouble instantiating two game objects into a scene that I've stored in two variables from a previous scene. I'm debugging to make sure that the variables are indeed populated with the necessary Gameobject, and they are. But when I try to instantiate these Gameobject into the new scene I'm getting the error:

```
ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null.
UnityEngine.Object.CheckNullArgument (System.Object arg, System.String message) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEngineObject.cs:238)
UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate (UnityEngine.Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEngineObject.cs:150)
UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate[GameObject] (UnityEngine.GameObject original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEngineObject.cs:205)
GameManager.LoadAnimalAvatar () (at Assets/_Coloring_Book/__Scripts/GameManager.cs:84)
AvatarFinalPreview.Start () (at Assets/_Coloring_Book/__Scripts/ColoringBook/AvatarFinalPreview.cs:9)
```

I'm assigning the gameobjects to variables in an object that persists from scene to scene (do not destroy) through a button click in the first scene that calls StoreAnimalAvatar and then when I switch to the next scene I have a script (AvatarFinalPreview.cs) that calls LoadAnimalAvatar in its Start function. I'm unsure why it's saying the object is null when in my debug log it shows that they exist. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
public void StoreAnimalAvatar()
    {
        GameObject uiObject3D = GameObject.Find("UIObject3D");
        GameObject animalToStore = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Avatar Preview");

        AnimalUIObject3D = uiObject3D;
        AnimalAvatar = animalToStore;

        Debug.Log("Animal Stored");
        Debug.Log(AnimalUIObject3D.name);
        Debug.Log(AnimalAvatar.name);
    }

    public void LoadAnimalAvatar()
    {
        GameObject canvas = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas");

        GameObject uiObject3D = Instantiate(AnimalUIObject3D, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        GameObject avatar = Instantiate(AnimalAvatar, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        avatar.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform);
    }
```

Comment: This has been asked so many times. `DontDestroyOnLoad(yourObject)`...

Comment: I have a gameobject that's not in the root though. When I've tried to use DontDestryOnLoad I get the error `DontDestroyOnLoad only work for root GameObjects or components on root GameObjects.` Is there another way to do this using your suggestion?

Comment: Try using prefabs.

Comment: @Draco18s the gameobjects I'm storing have custom textures that are getting applied at runtime.

Comment: Oh, in that case. Stop using scenes.

Comment: See `SceneManager.GetSceneByName` mentioned in my answer, If that doesn't work, use the first solution. There is no other way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I've tried to use DontDestryOnLoad I get the error
>   DontDestroyOnLoad only work for root GameObjects or components on root
>   GameObjects. Is there another way to do this using your suggestion?

You have three options:

**1**.Set the parent of that child object to null then call `DontDestroyOnLoad` on it. This will make the object not have a parent anymore so that `DontDestroyOnLoad` will work on it:

```
public GameObject yourChildObj;

....

yourChildObj.transform.parent = null;
DontDestroyOnLoad(yourChildObj);
```

**2**.Call `DontDestroyOnLoad` on the root of that object. Note that this will make the root object and its children live. You have to manually destroy other child objects and the parent after that since you only need that child object.

Get the root object of that child object. Get all the children under that root object except for that child object and store them in an array. Set the parent of that child object to null then call `DontDestroyOnLoad` on that child object. Now, destroy the stored children and the parent.

```
public GameObject yourChildObj;
...
Transform root = yourChildObj.transform.root;
ClearChildren(root, yourChildObj.transform);
```

The `ClearChildren` function:

```
public void ClearChildren(Transform targetRoot, Transform exclude)
{
    Debug.Log(targetRoot.childCount);
    int i = 0;

    //Array to hold all child obj
    GameObject[] allChildren = new GameObject[targetRoot.childCount];

    //Find all child obj and store to that array
    foreach (Transform child in targetRoot)
    {
        if (child != exclude)
        {
            allChildren[i] = child.gameObject;
            i += 1;
        }
    }

    //Remove exclude as the child
    exclude.parent = null;
    DontDestroyOnLoad(exclude);

    //Now destroy them
    foreach (GameObject child in allChildren)
    {
        if (child != null)
            DestroyImmediate(child.gameObject);
    }

    //Now destroy the parent
    if (targetRoot != null)
        DestroyImmediate(targetRoot);
}
```

**3**.Use [`SceneManager.GetSceneByName`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetSceneByName.html) to move that Object to another scene that has been loaded.

```
Scene yourNexScene = SceneManager.GetSceneByName("SceneName");
SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(yourChildObj, yourNexScene);
```

---

I prefer *option 1* but if you need more objects in the-same root to leave then *option 2* gives you chance to do that.

Comment: Thank you for this info. So if I go with option 1 and I set the parent to null, then once I go to the next scene I can just reassign the gameobject parent back into canvas, correct?

Comment: Yes, you just make it child of your canvas in your other scene and it should work just fine. The third option I mentioned does not need the use of `DontDestroyOnLoad` but #1 should be fine

Comment: I'm going to experiment with all three options, thank you so much for your incredibly valuable input.

Comment: Np. You can always comment if you run into related issues